# What is the type of scanner.Text() after parsing each line in a file?

Tags: go

I am currently reading a text file `input.txt` with the following inputs:

```
123
456
789
```

The code to parse it is:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    file, err := os.Open("input.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }   
    defer file.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    count := 0
    var line string
    for scanner.Scan() {
        count += 1
        line = scanner.Text()
        fmt.Println(line)
        if line == "123" {
            fmt.Println("EQUAL")
        }   
    }
}
```

Why does the first line of the file not match the hard coded string `123` in the code?

Comment: Print the bytes of the `line`: `fmt.Println([]byte(line))`. Check with a hex editor. Look for unprintable characters. Also check error after the `for` loop: `scanner.Err()`.

Comment: It works as you expect in [this playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/NxRZSsuwPD).

Comment: I see the issue, for some reason, the first line of the input file was `\xef\xbb\xbf123\n` instead of just `123\n`

Comment: @ThierryLam: that's a utf8 BOM, which you probably shouldn't have there (it's not required nor recommended)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is due to special characters in the file.  In this case the utf8 bom, but could be dos format `\r`, or other non-printable characters.